# Why if $n \mid m$, then $(a^n-1) \mid (a^m-1)$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

My Number Theory book says that for $n, m$ be positive integers and $a>1$, then

> $(a^n -1)\mid(a^m -1)$ if and only if $n\mid m$.

I understand the proof for only if part, but in if part the autor says "it is clear". However a tried to prove that but a get stuck. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Let ${\bf G}_n$ stand for the multiplicative group of $n$-th roots of unity. Then ${\bf G}_m\cap {\bf G}_n={\bf G}_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to show $(a^n-1) \mid (a^m-1)$ if $n \mid m$. If $n \mid m$ then $m = nk$ for some integer $k$, so you want to show $(a^n - 1) \mid (a^{nk}-1)$.

Now use the fact that $1^k = 1$ and recall that there is a factorisation for $x^k - y^k$; one of the terms will be $a^n - 1$.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: I think the question was about the converse direction.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the "only if" part?

Comment: No, the question is for if part, it is right.

Answer (score 2):

For one direction we have

**Hint:** Note that
$$
a^n-1\mid a^{nk}-1
$$

---

For the other direction, suppose that
$$
a^n-1\mid a^m-1\tag{1}
$$ 
Let $m=qn+r$ where $0\le r\lt n$. We know that
$$
a^n-1\mid a^{qn}-1\tag{2}
$$
Subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$ to get
$$
a^n-1\mid a^m-a^{qn}\tag{3}
$$
Since $\gcd(a^n-1,a)=1$, $(3)$ implies
$$
a^n-1\mid a^r-1\tag{4}
$$
Since $0\le r\lt n$, $(4)$ implies that $r=0$ (otherwise, a larger positive integer divides a smaller one). Since $r=0$, $m=qn$; that is, $n\mid m$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n|m$, say $m = dn$, then
$$
a^m-1 = {a^n}^d - 1 = (a^n - 1)((a^n)^{d-1} + (a^n)^{d-2} + \ldots + a^n + 1)
$$
can be checked directly or follows from setting $\alpha = a^n$ and $N = d$ in
$$
\alpha^N-1 = (\alpha-1)(\alpha^{N-1} + \alpha^{N-2} + \ldots + \alpha + 1).
$$

Alternatively, you could also just note that all the complex roots $\zeta$ of $x^n - 1$ must be roots of $x^m - 1$ if $n\mid m$, since $\zeta^n = 1 \implies \zeta^m = (\zeta^n)^d = 1$.