# Given positive integers $m$ and $n$, if $m | n$ then $2^m -1 | 2^n -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now:

Prove that, given positive integers $m$ and $n$, if $m | n$ then $2^m-1 | 2^n-1$.

I can't seem to get any traction with this problem.  Most of my approaches to the problem depend on knowing something about $\gcd(m,n)$, and all I know from the problem is that $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$ when $m,n \neq 1$.

Can anyone give me a hint or suggest an approach I'm not seeing?

Thanks

Comment: This has surely been asked and answered here many times. The closest I could find, though, is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561077/pm-1-mid-pn-1-leftrightarrow-m-mid-n

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Ah, geez.  Sorry I couldn't find anything in my search.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Jim: if I had any clue how to search math-y stuff on here, I could have provided many more (and more helpful)links!

Comment: You don't seem to be thinking about this the right way: You say that your approach depends on knowing about $\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$. In this case, you know *a lot* about this number: If $m\mid n$, then $\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)=m$.

Comment: Granted, google gave me this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529111/why-if-n-mid-m-then-an-1-mid-am-1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 2):

If $m\vert n$ then $2^n-1 = 2^{mk} - 1 = (2^m)^k -1 = \left(2^m - 1\right)\left((2^m)^{k-1} + (2^m)^{k-2} + \cdots +1\right)$

so  $2^m -1\vert 2^n-1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2^m \equiv 1\pmod{2^m-1}$. If $m$ divides $n$, then $n=km$ for some positive integer $k$. It follows that 
$$2^n =2^{mk}=(2^m)^k \equiv 1^k=1\pmod{2^m-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better than this, in that they help learn concepts that are important, but: it's pretty easy to prove this by induction on $n/m$, since $(2^{n+m}-1)-(2^n-1)$ is easily seen to be a multiple of $2^m-1$.